# Something is wrong with process and status of child process

Tags: c, process

I cannot understand whats wrong…. It does not give me any messages returning from executing program in parent process. Can somebody explain and help what is wrong???? thank you. Any help will be appreciated.

Basically, my program should read a user id and password, creates a new process to run the VALIDATE program (which is in file validate.c), sends to VALIDATE program the user id and password, and prints a message "Password verified" if the user id and password matched or either "Invalid password" or "No such user" depending on the return value of the validate program.) 0 - everything is ok, 2 and 3 smth went wrong.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

#define MAXLINE 256
#define MAXPASSWD 10

void
strip (char *str, int capacity)
{
  char *ptr;
  if ((ptr = strchr (str, '\n')) == NULL)
    {
      str[capacity - 1] = '\0';
    }
  else
    {
      *ptr = '\0';
    }
}


int
main (void)
{
  char userid[MAXLINE];
  char password[MAXLINE];
  pid_t pid;
  int fd[2];
  /* Read a user id and password from stdin */
  printf ("User id:\n");
  if ((fgets (userid, MAXLINE, stdin)) == NULL)
    {
      fprintf (stderr, "Could not read from stdin\n");
      exit (1);
    }
  strip (userid, MAXPASSWD);
  printf ("Password:\n");
  if ((fgets (password, MAXLINE, stdin)) == NULL)
    {
      fprintf (stderr, "Could not read from stdin\n");
      exit (1);
    }
  strip (password, MAXPASSWD);
  pipe (fd);
  pid = fork ();
  if (pid == -1)
    {
      printf ("Error making process\n");
      return (-1);
    }
  if (pid == 0)
    {
      close (fd[0]);
      printf ("Hey I am the child with pid: %d\n", getpid ());
      dup2 (fd[0], 0);
      execl ("/h/u15/c2/00/validate.c", "validate.c", NULL);

    }
  int status;

  if (pid > 0)
    {

      write (fd[1], password, (strlen (password) - 1));
      write (fd[1], userid, (strlen (userid) - 1));
      printf ("status %d\n", WEXITSTATUS (status));
      if (waitpid (pid, &status, 0) == 0)
        {
          printf ("status %d\n", WEXITSTATUS (status));
          if (WIFEXITED (status) && WEXITSTATUS (status))
            {
              if (WEXITSTATUS (status) == 3)
                {
                  printf (" No such a user\n");
                }
              else if (WEXITSTATUS (status) == 2)
                {
                  printf ("Invalid password");
                }
              else
                printf ("Password verified\n");
            }
        }    
    }
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You appear to have made a pipe using `pipe`, but have not used `dup2` to make `stdin` or `stdout` use those file descriptors. So how is the program you `execl` meant to know which fd to read from?

From the man page for `pipe`:

> `pipe()`  creates  a  pipe,  a unidirectional data channel that can be used for interprocess communication. The array `pipefd` is used to return two file descriptors referring to the ends of the pipe. `pipefd[0]` refers to the read  end  of the pipe. `pipefd[1]` refers to the write end of the pipe.  Data written to the write end of the pipe is buffered by the kernel until it is read from the read end of the pipe. For further details, see `pipe(7).`

In your program the parent is meant to be writing to the pipe, and (I assume) the child (which does the `execl`) is meant to be reading from the pipe.

So the parent should be doing something like:

```
close (fd[0]); /* close read end of pipe - NB you have close(fd[1]) currently */
write (fd[1], ...);
```

and the child should be doing something like:

```
close (fd[1]); /* close write end of pipe */
dup2 (fd[0], STDIN_FILENO); /* STDIN_FILENO is 0 */
close (fd[0]); /* now we have this on FD we don't need it any more *.
execl ( ... something that works with STDIN ...)
```

I presume you are just relying on the exit status from validate command? If not, and you need to capture what is written to `STDOUT`, you'll need *another* pipe for that.

Below you'll find a fixed up version of your code that gets as far as I can get it without your password verifier:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

#define MAXLINE 256
#define MAXPASSWD 10

void
strip (char *str, int capacity)
{
  char *ptr;
  if ((ptr = strchr (str, '\n')) == NULL)
    {
      str[capacity - 1] = '\0';
    }
  else
    {
      *ptr = '\0';
    }
}


int
main (void)
{
  char userid[MAXLINE];
  char password[MAXLINE];
  pid_t pid;
  int fd[2];
  /* Read a user id and password from stdin */
  printf ("User id:\n");
  if ((fgets (userid, MAXLINE, stdin)) == NULL)
    {
      fprintf (stderr, "Could not read from stdin\n");
      exit (1);
    }
  strip (userid, MAXPASSWD);
  printf ("Password:\n");
  if ((fgets (password, MAXLINE, stdin)) == NULL)
    {
      fprintf (stderr, "Could not read from stdin\n");
      exit (1);
    }
  strip (password, MAXPASSWD);
  pipe (fd);
  pid = fork ();
  if (pid == -1)
    {
      printf ("Error making process\n");
      return (-1);
    }
  if (pid == 0)
    {
      close (fd[0]);
      fprintf (stderr, "Hey I am the child with pid: %d\n", getpid ());
      dup2 (fd[0], 0);
      execl ("/h/u15/c2/00/validate.c", "validate.c", NULL);
      exit (1);
    }
  int status;

  if (pid > 0)
    {
      write (fd[1], password, (strlen (password) - 1));
      write (fd[1], userid, (strlen (userid) - 1));
      if (waitpid (pid, &status, 0) != -1)
        {
          printf ("status %d\n", WEXITSTATUS (status));
          if (WIFEXITED (status) && WEXITSTATUS (status))
            {
              if (WEXITSTATUS (status) == 3)
                {
                  printf (" No such a user\n");
                }
              else if (WEXITSTATUS (status) == 2)
                {
                  printf ("Invalid password");
                }
              else
                printf ("Password verified\n");
            }
        }
    }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: You should `close` the fd in the parent if you are using it in the child, and vice versa. However, the `close` in one does not need to be before the `dup2` takes place in the other; you just need to not use it save to close it.

Comment: dup2(fd[0],0);
write(fd[1],password,(strlen(password)-1)); @abligh

Comment: @user3247903, actually you have another bug. You are closing `fd[1]`, then you are writing to it. You need to write to the side of the pipe you are *not* closing. The `dup2` needs to go before the `exec`.

Comment: i think i added everything….

Comment: it just prints message "Hey I am child with pid ….."

Comment: I modified this slightly, to use `fprintf(stderr, ...)` to send your debugging to `STDERR` and not interfere with the pipe, and also added an `exit(1)` after the `exec` in case it fails (which it will without the validator). I see both the 'Hey I'm the child' and a 'status 0'; I think that's because you are printing the status before you do the `waitpid`.

Comment: @user3247903, oh your test on the return value of `waitpid` should be `!=-1` as `waitpid` returns the PID of the process whose status has changed on success, not zero. With that I get a sensible result. However, I suggest you use exit status 0 for password verified, or all passwords will be verified if your verifier cannot be `exec`'d.

Comment: so i need just to change waitpid !=-1?! @abligh

Comment: well i have changed but still no messages…… ;((

Comment: I have posted the code that I have in the answer. Note that you still have some issues beyond the scope of this question (like you are writing the username and password with no separator and omitting the last character), i.e. if they are `foo` and `bar` then you will write `foba`.

Comment: it gives me for all password verified

Comment: It will do that if the `exec` errors, as you are treating an error in `exec` as exit code 1. I think you are now beyond problems with the `pipe`. See my comment 1 up (edited) for some other issues with your code. However, I think this is now beyond the scope of this question. If you've found things useful so far, an upvote would be appreciated.